# Jfrog Artifactory and Azure migration

Tags: azure, devops, artifactory, artifacts

We use Jfrog Artifactory 7.x and are interested in migrating to Azure. Does anyone know procedures, tools, etc., we can use to perform a successful migration?
We did some research by trying to find something helpful.

Comment: Is it self-hosted to cloud migration? If the answer is yes, you can find the full guide here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Transfer+Artifactory+Configuration+and+Files+to+JFrog+Cloud

Answer (score 0):

I believe this [KB article](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-is-the-best-way-to-migrate-a-large-artifactory-instance-with-minimal-downtime/) has the information on migrating from one server to another.